# Is there a MySQL query that can encode to JSON in exactly this way?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I have 2 tables like

```
                    work_assets
  -----------------------------------------------------
   id  |     asseturl    |    previmgurl     |  carid
  -----------------------------------------------------
    1  |    "pic1.jpg"   |     "pic2.jpg"    |    1
    2  |    "pic3.jpg"   |     "pic4.jpg"    |    1
    3  |    "pic5.jpg"   |     "pic6.jpg"    |    2
    .  |      ...        |        ...        |    .
    .  |      ...        |        ...        |    .


                       cases
  -----------------------------------------------------
   id  |       ...       |    carid   |      ...
  -----------------------------------------------------
    1  |        ...      |     1      |      ... 
    2  |        ...      |     2      |      ...         
    3  |        ...      |     69     |      ... 
    .  |        ...      |    ...     |      ...
    .  |        ...      |    ...     |      ...
```

and my hope is that I can perform some type of query `Q` that can get me to JSON that is basically the `cases` table with a one-to-many relationship from its `carid` colummn to the associated `asseturl` and `previmgurl`, like

```
[
 { id : 1, ..., assetinfo: [ { asseturl : "pic1.jpg", previmgurl: "pic2.jpg"}, { asseturl : "pic3.jpg", previmgurl: "pic4.jpg"} ], ... },
 { id : 2, ... }, 
 { id:  3, ... }, 
     .
     .
     .
]
```

Setup:

```
var cases =  <?php
                   $Q = ????; 
                   echo json_encode($wpdb->get_results($Q));
              ?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it. You would have to query the data, loop over those results and build an array in the format you want. Queries would only pull out data in 2d (rows of columns), not 3d or 4d (rows of columns with one or more columns another array of data). Ideally it would likely be two queries, loop over the first and inject the second as a sub-array under the first.

Comment: If you are using some framework that has a ORM (or you can add one to your project) you might leverage that to deliver the result set you want. If not then it's up to you to fetch the data and arrange it however you want before json encoding it.

Comment: Given that there is a php tag on this question, I suggest that you write the code that serializes the data in that language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you really don't need to do that json transformation on mysql side because it is not very efficient and has almost no sense.

But just to show that it is possible (in opposite of @bannmatt opinion) here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bffb/7

```
SELECT c.*,
  CONCAT('assetinfo : [ ', 
     COALESCE(
        GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT("{ asseturl: ",
                             wa.asseturl,
                             ', previmgurl: ', 
                             wa.previmgurl," }")
        ),
     ''),
   ' ]')
FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN work_assets wa
ON c.carid = wa.carid
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Nice thinking :)  One question about this - when you get the 'assetinfo' field in the query results won't this be one big string which would be treated as a string rather than an array of objects if you call `json_encode` on the query results?

Comment: @bunnmatt that depends on what wordpress function `get_results` return. you can check in codex for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think you will be able to get a single SQL query from your database which will serialise into JSON the way you want, because the structure you describe is multi-dimensional - i.e. an array nested within another array.