# How to do mysql SELECT json

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to select json **within** mysql? Or do I need to use concatenation to build it? I need to do a large json update statement and I'd rather do it within the db so I don't have to iterate of tens of millions of rows. Is there a better approach than:

```
SELECT CONCAT('{"field1: "', field1, '"}') FROM mytable
```

Comment: There are no built-in JSON functions in MySQL. Maybe you can find a UDF with a google search.

Comment: there was almost the same question just yesterday. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/32957499/4421474 maybe it will help

Comment: Concat is limited. Since you have million of rows, It couldn't be done.

Comment: @RubahMalam is right. You'll probably run into the `group_concat_max_length` limit if you try to do this for a large result. Use `fetchAll()` in PDO to fetch all the rows into an array, and then `json_encode()` to encode the whole thing in one step.

Comment: I agree with others, you probably shouldn't do that on mysql side. try to describe your problem deeply. It is possible that someone will give you another idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

- mysql Server (since Version 8.0): `SELECT [field with json blob]->>"$.json_field" FROM mytable;` [see](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)
- mariaDB Server (since Version 10.26) `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT([field with json blob], "$.json_field") from mytable` [see](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).